# Issue: Scrolling back up SwipeRefreshLayout + Webview( Elemen HTML CSS: position:fixed)

Tags: android, android-webview, css-position, fixed, swiperefreshlayout

Div Element CSS: position: Fixed,
Scrolling down is no issue, but when I try to scroll back up, the page does not scroll and instead triggers the swipe to refresh functionality
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jjrg8.gif)

**activity_main**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/web_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone">

        </WebView>
    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**MainActivity**

```js
private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            mySwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mySwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I see a lot of .setRefreshing(true); you sure that shouldn't be mySwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false); in onPageFinished()?

Comment: I tried changing it but it still doesn't work

in App https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sX0fJ4YGmeU
in Chrome https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fd5l2-4aOr4

Comment: (My personal opinion) don't use SwipeRefreshLayout with WebView. Instead create a button for your desired functionality.